# Is it possible to visit different Dimensions without modding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm not allowed to install mods. Are there any non-mod ways to visit other dimensions in Minecraft?

Comment: you mean like The Nether or The End?

Answer (score 3):

The only "dimensions" you can access in the Vanilla version of Minecraft is the Nether, and the End.

[The Nether](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether) is basically a "Hell" dimension, full of fire and lava and evil creatures. You can access this dimension through the use of a [Nether Portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether#Accessing).

[The End](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End) is a much darker dimension full of floating islands hovering in the void, which is home to the [Ender Dragon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon), and [End Cities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city). This can be found by locating an [End Portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End#Accessing)

Answer (score 0):

Without mods or very complicated commands it is impossible to get to a dimension other then the End or the Nether. "New Dimensions" created by commands (as far as i've seen) Have basically just been synthetic environments and mini maps. Basically, without mods it is impossible to truly have another dimension. Sorry if this wasn't the answer you were looking for.